# How can I understand and perform Webelement with click ActionChains in selenium to 'update' webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am learning to use selenium to scrape some data from an Online Travel Agent for a Data Science course. I can get the driver with initial page_source. However, since the OTA will not give all the flights info at the very beginning, there is a 'show more results' button there for people to click.

In order to 'click' that button, I have the following codes and there is no warning or error after running it. However, the WebDriver itself is not updated after this 'click event'. I am wondering

1. is that because I misunderstand the webdriver's behavior? I am thinking that every time, when the click is triggered, the response will be updated accordingly. Meaning that, driver.page_source will be updated, just like I click the button from the browser side and now content is loaded to the screen.
2. or it is because of the false implementation.

Here is my code and the corresponding output:

```
clickable = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ULvh-button.show-more-button')
print(clickable.text)
print('before click ' + str(len(driver.page_source)))
ActionChains(driver)\
        .context_click(clickable)\
        .perform()
print('after click ' + str(len(driver.page_source)))
```

Results are:

```
Show more results
before click 865183
after click 865183
```